# Добавление наследников в отдельный лист

Tags: c#

изучаю ООП, не могу разобраться с следующей проблемой. Имеются вольеры с животными `Aviary`. У каждого животного `Animal` есть пол `Gender` и издаваемый животным звук `Sound`. Я хочу создать лист с вольерами `aviaries` и затем в каждый вольер добавлять сразу наследника, т.е. `Pig` или `Frog`.

Т.е. просто лист с животными я могу сделать например вот так

```
List<Animal> pigsHouse = new List<Animal>
            {
                new Animal("M", "Хрю-Хрю"),
                new Animal("Ж", "Хрю-Хрю"),
                new Animal("M", "Хрю-Хрю"),
            };
```

Но я же изучаю ООП, и хочу добавлять наследника, с уже готовым звуком, прописанным в классе и лишь просто дописывать пол. Т.е. в идеале должно быть что-то такое:

```
Aviary aviary = new Aviary()
                {
                    new Pig("M"),
                    new Pig("Ж"),
                    new Pig("M"),
                };
```

Но такая инициализация выдает мне ошибку, потому что здесь создан просто объект, а не лист

Вот весь код:

```
class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Aviary> aviaries = new List<Aviary>();
            Aviary aviary = new Aviary();
        }
    }

    class Aviary
    {
        public List<Animal> Animals { get; }

        public Aviary()
        {
            Animals = new List<Animal>();
        }
    }

    class Animal
    {
        public string Gender { get; private set; }
        public string Sound { get; private set; }

        public Animal(string gender, string sound)
        {
            Gender = gender;
            Sound = sound;
        }
    }

    class Pig : Animal
    {
        public Pig(string gender, string sound) : base(gender, "Хрю-Хрю") { }
    }

    class Frog : Animal
    {
        public Frog(string gender, string sound) : base(gender, "Ква-Ква") { }
    }

    class Duck : Animal
    {
        public Duck(string gender, string sound) : base(gender, "Кря-Кря") { }
    }

    class Dog : Animal
    {
        public Dog(string gender, string sound) : base(gender, "Гав-Гав") { }
    }
```

Всего должно быть 4 вольера. Подскажите где моя ошибка и что я делаю не так?

Comment: [Collection initializers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers#collection-initializers)

Comment: @tym32167 но тут про добавление наследников ничего не говорится, я же хотел объяснения, как мне сделать лучше или почему то, как я делаю, не будет работать

Comment: То, что вы патаетесь сделать, никак не связано с неследниками. Вы пытаетесь использовать свой класс Aviary как вы используете `List<>`, но `List<>` является коллекцией и поддерживает инициализацию для коллекций, а ваш класс нет.  .

Comment: Если вам нужны просто коллекции с животными конкретного типа, то создавайте их так: `var pigs = new List<Pig>`, `var frogs = new List<Frog>` и т. д. | Нужно ли создавать отдельный класс, унаследованный от `List` или включающий его в себя? Рекомендую почитать ответы здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/q/21692193/5045688.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы хотите сделать свой список а делаете композицию

```
class Aviary:List<Animal>
{
      
}
```

Это будет работать с вашим идеалом.
Если хотите оставить

```
class Aviary
{
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; }

    public Aviary()
    {
        Animals = new List<Animal>();
    }
}
```

То думаю нужно инициализировать Animals так

```
  Aviary aviary = new Aviary()
            {
               Animals = new List<Animal> {
                new Pig("M"),
                new Pig("Ж"),
                new Pig("M"),
              }
            };
```

Comment: Если реализовать в классе IEnumerable и добавить метод Add, то можно будет пользоваться синтаксисом инициализации коллекции прямо на классе

Comment: @АндрейNOP да конечно, я про100 указал вариант без больших изменений в класс.